Java - тернарный оператор и классы
Имеется следующий код:
class Random {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean f = true; // false
        var randomClass = f ? new A() : new B();
        randomClass.randomMethod();
    }
}

class A {
    public void randomMethod() {
        System.out.println("Method in class A");
    }
}

class B {
    public void randomMethod() {
        System.out.println("Method in class B");
    }
}

По моему предположению, он должен был в зависимости от f инициализировать переменную randomClass либо как ссылочную переменную на экземпляр класса А, либо на B. Но на практике, код выше даже не скомпилировался.
Вне зависимости от значения f, выведение типов присваивает переменной randomClass ссылку не на экземпляр класса A или B, а на экземпляр класса Object. Из-за того, что в Object метод randomMethod() не определен, сам код не компилируется.
Почему так происходит, ведь с точки зрения логики тернарный оператор должен быть равносилен следующей записи:
if (f) {
    var randomClass = new A();
} else {
    var randomClass = new B();
}

То есть в зависимости от f, randomClass должен ссылаться либо на экземпляр класса А, либо на экземпляр класса B.
Мне не нужны альтернативные решения того, как можно это реализовать без использования тернарного оператора. Нужно именно объяснение, почему тернарный оператор выдает такой результат.

var - это синтаксический сахар. По факту компилятор должен завести переменную такого типа, в которую можно поместить и класс A и класс B. Обычно в таких случаях используется прародитель всех объектов Object. Что вы и наблюдаете.
Что тут можно сделать - описать интерфейс, в котором есть randomMethod и унаследовать от него оба ваших класса. А перед вызовом метода преобразовать переменную randomClass к этому интерфейсу. В переменную то интерфейс записать всё-равно не получится, в переменной всё-равно будет Object.
Ну либо сделать базовый класс для ваших объектов с этим методом, и помещать в переменную объект базового класса.

Спасибо большое. Применение var с классами я вроде бы понял, но все еще остался вопрос, как var понимает, какой "общий" тип нужно применить для примитива и объекта? Например, var a = f ? 10 : "string" компилируется вполне нормально и значение a можно даже использовать (например, вывести в консоль).

@forq-forq Я не настолько хорошо знаю именно Java. Но я бы проверил, какого типа объект получается у вас в a. А вообще значение f у вас прямо в код зашито константой? Вы примели в точности именно тот код, который у вас вызвал проблемы? Просто если зашить константу, то мне кажется компилятор выберет конкретную ветку и присвоит переменной конкретный тип. Object будет получаться только если значение f не определено на этапе компиляции. Возможно, поведение компилятора ещё будет ещё зависеть от ключей компиляции. Что-то у меня не сходится между вашим кодом и наблюдаемым поведением.

Я сделал ряд тестов и в итоге понял, что:

примитив и примитив: переменная получает тип согласно автоматическому повышению типов (int, byte -> int) (int, double -> double).
объект и объект: переменная получает наиболее спецефичный общий класс, либо Object, если два класса никак не связаны.



примитив + объект: переменная получается ссылочной, но при этом общий тип не Object. В тесте со строкой и целым числом я в итоге получил, что строка имеет тип java.lang.String, а число -  java.lang.Integer.


@forq-forq А, ну то есть частично компилятор разруливает до конца случаи, когда всё понятно с ветвлением уже в процессе компиляции, а частично нет. Интересно.

Возможно, что в 3 тесте я ошибся. И общий тип там все таки Object. Получается, что var если в тернарном операторе встречает примитив и объект, то он распознает примитив как объект (int -> Integer) и автоматически присваивает общий тип Object.

Во всяком случае, использование одновременно и примитива, и объекта в тернарном операторе, как по мне, не самая нужная вещь. Ответ на основной вопрос о том, как работает var с объектами я получил, поэтому спасибо вам еще раз. Всего доброго!

@forq-forq Повторюсь - это может зависеть от того, задана ли переменная f прямо в коде константой или приходит откуда-то снаружи. Но даже если и задана, результат компиляции может зависеть от настроек компилятора. Если компилятору на этапе компиляции уже понятно, что выполняется всегда только одна ветка, то он просто выкинет всё лишнее и сведёт эту конструкцию до тип переменная = значение, тернарный оператор он просто выкинет.

В коде я использовал f и как константу, и как значение, получаемое от пользователя. Результат один и тот же. Это по сути просто какое-то условие, в вопросе я привел его в виде константы лишь для упрощения.

@forq-forq А зря вы смешиваете эти два варианта. Скорее всего поведение компилятора будет отличаться. Все компиляторы, не только Java, пользуются тем знанием, что какие-то штуки уже известны как константы на этапе компиляции, и упрощают код на основании этого знания, выкидывая лишнее.

Тернарный оператор равносилен следующей записи
var randomClass;

if (f) {
    randomClass = new A();
} else {
    randomClass = new B();
}

Здесь видно, что переменной нужно сначала указать тип. Так как типы разные, общий тип для обоих классов будет Object

Оператор var v = b?foo:bar; на самом деле превращается в:
T v;
if(b){
   v=foo;
}else{
   v=bar;
}

Где T — наиболее специфичный общий тип для foo и bar.
В твоём случае общий тип у A и B это Object.

Вы всё время путаете процесс компиляции программы и процесс её выполнения. "Вне зависимости от значения f, выведение типов присваивает" - здесь значение анализируется в процессе выполнения, а выведение типов происходит в процессе компиляции.
"То есть в зависимости от f, randomClass должен ссылаться либо на экземпляр класса А, либо на экземпляр класса B." - это относится к периоду выпонения. Но как об этом узнает компилятор?
Остальное объяснено в других ответах.
